# Django setting media storage in settings issue

Tags: django

In my development.py settings I have the following:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

...

MEDIA_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location='/Users/myuser/myfolder')
```

and in my staging.py settings I have this:

```
from django_s3_storage.storage import S3Storage

...

MEDIA_STORAGE = S3Storage(aws_s3_bucket_name=DOCUMENTS_BUCKET)
```

The development.py settings file causes no issues and storing files works fine. However, importing the staging settings breaks on this line, `MEDIA_STORAGE = ...` so it cannot build. I had the exact same line outside the settings file, in the models.py where it's used. It worked normally. Should it be written differently if it's extracted into settings?

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: @wencakisa the error I get is as if the whole settings file isn't imported at all (The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.), but I've added print statements throughout the settings file and the only print that doesn't show is the print right after this line `MEDIA_STORAGE`. The print statement right before that line prints ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you import `from django_s3_storage.storage import S3Storage` in `settings.py`. Probably for circular dependency issues(I am not sure).

But, you can write a new storage class, for example like this:

```
# utilities/storages.py

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaRootS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
```

Then use it in settings:

```
MEDIA_STORAGE = 'utilities.storages.MediaRootS3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: I understand. Will try it and get back to you.